# Haskell checking return type of function from another function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a Haskell code that has two functions:

The first function:

```
functionA :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
```

The second one:

```
functionB :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

What I want to do is to recurse on every element of [Int] and feed it into functionB. If function B returns an Int, then move to the next element, if it returns Nothing, then functionA returns nothing too.

Any idea how best to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to write `functionA` by using `functionB`? What happens if more than one of the `Int`s gives an `Int` instead of `Nothing`? Just return the first one that worked, or return a list of all of the ones that worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sequence` to take `[Maybe Int]` to `Maybe [Int]`

```
functionA ints = sequence (map functionB ints)
```

Generally this combination of `sequence` and `map` is called `mapM`.

```
functionA ints = mapM functionB ints
```

Comment: A bit confused on this, could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has few things that are not clear hence I am making few assumptions.
`functionA` is like a fold as it transform a `[Int]` to `Maybe Int` but before folding the ints it calls `functionB` to transform each integer into a `Maybe Int` where `Nothing` result indicate a failure in transformation and which leads to failure of the `functionA` and making it return `Nothing`.

```
import Control.Applicative

functionA :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
functionA nums = foldl (\x y -> (+) <$> x <*> y) (Just 0) $ map functionB nums

functionB :: Int -> Maybe Int
functionB 2 = Nothing
functionB x = Just (x+x)
```

In the example above, the `+` is used in the fold operation and `functionB` fails on number 2

Answer (score 0):

J. Abrahamson answered right, but he named the result function unusually and it confused you.

Let we have ints:

```
ints :: [a]

functionA :: [a] -> Maybe a

functionB :: a -> Maybe a
```

So we wish to get map `functionB`:

```
functionC :: a -> Maybe [a]
functionC ints = mapM functionB ints
```

but `functionC` has result type `Maybe [a]`, not `[a]`, so we use `fmap`

```
result :: [a] -> Maybe a
result ints = join $ fmap functionA $ functionC ints
```

And we also use `join` to get rid of `Maybe (Maybe a)` result

Or let's write in one line:

```
result :: [a] -> Maybe a
result = join . fmap functionA . mapM functionB
```

**UPDATED**

But in this solution always calculates all `ints`.
If we wish to stop calculating, we need to have `mapIfAllJust` function, like this:

```
result :: [a] -> Maybe a
result = join . fmap functionA . sequence . mapIfAllJust functionB

mapIfAllJust :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [Maybe b]
mapIfAllJust _ []     = []
mapIfAllJust f (x:xs) = go f (f x) [] xs
where
    go _ Nothing _    _         = [Nothing]
    go _ pr      used []        = pr : used
    go f pr      used (nxt:rst) = go f (f nxt) (pr : used) rst
```